# Можно ли объединить запросы в один

Tags: mysql, sql

Доброе время суток,
Можно ли объединить следующие запросы в один запрос?:

```
select SUM(PROFIT) as PROFIT 
from ARCHIVE 
where PROFIT > 0.0 and DATE_END_RATE between '13.01.2017' and '14.01.2017'
```

С запросом

```
select SUM(PROFIT) as LOSS 
from ARCHIVE 
where PROFIT < 0.0 and DATE_END_RATE between '13.01.2017' and '14.01.2017'
```

А также

```
select * 
from ARCHIVE 
where DATE_END_RATE between '13.01.2017' and '14.01.2017'
```

чтобы сразу вывести все записи таблицы ARCHIVE, и еще добавить в нее два поля "PROFIT"  и "LOSS", в которых отобразить соответствующие положительные и отрицательные суммы?

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объединить первые два несложно:

```
select SUM(CASE WHEN PROFIT > 0.0 THEN PROFIT END) as PROFIT 
,      SUM(CASE WHEN PROFIT < 0.0 THEN PROFIT END) as LOSS 
from ARCHIVE 
where DATE_END_RATE between '13.01.2017' and '14.01.2017'
```

Относительно третьего - это будут разные уровни группировки, и совмещение их в одном запросе не имеет смысла.

Comment: т.е. всетаки придеться дергать сервер несколько раз?

Comment: Вы хотите получить и список операций, и итоговые суммы с плюсами/минусами? Но эти выборки даже по количеству полей различаются - ну как их собрать в один набор данных? Единственное, что можно (если коннектор позволяет) - отправить два запроса одним пакетом и получить в ответ два набора данных.

Comment: Я думал можно каким-то образом к выборке всей талицы (запрос №3), добавить два поля "profit" и "loss" и в каждой их строке отобразить и "плюс" и "минус".  Но  если нельзя так нельзя... Не view делать в самом же деле...

Comment: Почему нельзя? можно... вот только оверхед от дополнительных данных в КАЖДОЙ записи сожрёт весь твой призрачный выигрыш от избавления от второго запроса...

Answer (score 1):

Оконных функций, позволяющих на каждой строке получить сразу сумму нескольких строк в MySQL нет, поэтому приходится накапливать результаты в переменных и во внешнем запросе их выводить.

```
select *, @p as PROFIT, @l as LOST
  from (
   select *,
          @p:=@p+if(PROFIT>0,PROFIT,0),
          @l:=@l+if(PROFIT<0,PROFIT,0)
     from ARCHIVE, (select @p:=0,@l:=0) A
    where DATE_END_RATE between '13.01.2017' and '14.01.2017'
  ) X
```